# Compiling and linking Swift plus Objective C code from the OS X command-line

Tags: objective-c, macos, linker, swift

Compiling Swift from an OS X command-line:

```
swift -sdk $(xcrun --show-sdk-path --sdk macosx) test.swift
```

Compiling Objective C from the command-line:

```
clang -lobjc -framework Foundation -c testObject.m
```

I can add the -c option to either compiler to produce .o files.

How can I link these two source files into one app?

Or is more needed to build?

Comment: Are you asking without the usage of Xcode 6 at all?

Comment: You need to install Xcode6 to get the Swift tools.  But one should be able to compile from the Terminal without using the full IDE.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**TL;DR**: It's preferable to use the Xcode tooling, since there's a lot of stuff going on. But it's possible to only use command line tools.

I'll warn you that this is a quick and dirty example of how to compile and run a `.m` and a `.swift` file, linked against Cocoa and the Swift runtime. I'm not even trying to follow the best practices on either side.

Let's assume you have an Objective-C class:

```
$ cat C.h
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface C : NSObject
@property (retain) NSString *c;
@end

$ cat C.m
#import "C.h"

@implementation C

- (id)init {
  self = [super init];
  self.c = @"Hello world!";
  return self;
}

@end
```

And you have a Swift file that uses that class:

```
$ cat S.swift
let c = C()

println(c.c)
```

You just need to compile the Objective-C and Swift files to `.o` files, separately:

```
xcrun clang C.m -o C.o -c
# Be sure to import the bridge header (our only header in this example)
xcrun swiftc -c S.swift -import-objc-header C.h -F /System/Library/Frameworks -I/usr/include
```

As you can see, we had to manually include the framework and header paths, to have the Swift compiler locate the proper files (it might be best to have it look for them in the SDK, not in the currently installed files, btw (with `xcrun --show-sdk-path`)).

Then we simply need to link them, pulling all the Swift and Objective-C runtime libs. Since `swift` by default pulls the Objective-C libraries, we don't even need to specify much:

```
xcrun swiftc -o app C.o S.o
```

Behold, our executable is linked and we can run it!

```
$ ./app
Hello world!
```

This is all very interesting, but I would advise against using these tools directly unless you're actually making a build system for your project that targets them and have a good reason not to use Xcode/`xcodebuild`.

Comment: Currently running the swift compiler requires `swiftc` so, e.g.: `xcrun swiftc -o app C.o S.o`

Comment: Thanks telliott99, I fixed it now (sorry about the delay).

Comment: It doesn't work for `swiftc` compiler on version `Apple Swift version 2.2`. I got the following error:

`/Users/my-user/swift-objc/./C.h:1:9: error: could not build module 'Foundation'
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`

And inside the `/System/Library/Frameworks/` I have all the frameworks needed. Can you help me?

Comment: Update for newer Swift: That `-F` should be `/System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa` and `println` should just be `print` for this example to build in 2017.

Comment: @uliwitness This is what worked for me on Swift 5.2:  `xcrun swiftc -c foo.swift -F /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa -I/usr/include`