# How can I run an Objective-C library on Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to run [this](https://github.com/Lukas-Stuehrk/XMLHTTPRequest) library from a `.swift` file. The sample code includes this snippet:

```
#import <XMLHTTPRequest/XMLHTTPRequest.h>

...

JSContext *jsContext = [JSContext new];
XMLHttpRequest *xmlHttpRequest = [XMLHttpRequest new];
[xmlHttpRequest extend:jsContext];
```

I believe this is Objective-C. How can I run that same code given that I have a `.swift` file?

Comment: You should put it in an objective-C file, then create a bridging header for your project and import it there. This will expose it to your Swift project and you can use it regularly like you would any Swift class.

Comment: Seems like you didn't pay enough attention to the question. Notice that thread (which I looked up previously) is asking how to call Objective-C from XCode. I said all I have is a `.swift` file, not a XCode project. That answer doesn't apply. This is, thus, not a duplicate.

Comment: You didn't say that you weren't using Xcode in your question.  You can't call Objective-C from a plain `.swift` file, what you are asking is not possible.  You need to compile it into a binary at the very least using Xcode, or clang from the command line.  See [Compiling and linking Swift plus Objective C code from the OS X command-line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24131476/2415822).