# How to link CocoaPods library without Xcode (integrate_targets false)

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, cocoapods

I have a swift project that is built without Xcode. I want to use a library from CocoaPods with it. Given following `Podfile`:

```
platform :osx, '10.11'
install! 'cocoapods', :integrate_targets => false
target 'Foo' do
  pod "PlainPing"
end
pre_install do |installer|
  installer.analysis_result.specifications.each do |s|
    s.swift_version = '4.2' unless s.swift_version
  end
end
```

I can easily build the library into `.a` and `.swiftmodule` files:

```
pod install
cd Pods
xcodebuild
```

But using the compiled library from `swiftc` seems to be tricky, I can't guess correct search path spells or google them. My best bet:

```
swiftc -I ./build/Release/PlainPing -L ./build/Release/PlainPing -lPlainPing main.swift
```

Fails with

```
main.swift:2:8: error: cannot load underlying module for 'PlainPing'
```

It seems that `-L` library search path is working, but `swiftc` is missing something to actually use an `.a` library file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Version with manual CocoaPod compilation

To compile `CocoaPods` library which includes both Swift and Objective-C code do the following:

1. Copy your `main.swift` to `Pods/PlainPing/Pod/Classes`
2. Compile `PlainPing` Objective-C code
3. Emit `PlainPing.swiftmodule`
4. Compile `PlainPing` emitting objects
5. Compile app including emitted objects and `main.swift`

Script (copy & paste into terminal):

```
 echo "1. Compiling Objective-C code" && \
 clang \
      -c \
      -fmodules \
      -fobjc-weak \
      -arch x86_64 \
      -w \
      SimplePing.m \
 && \
 echo "2. Emitting PlainPing.swiftmodule" && \
 swiftc \
      -emit-module \
      -module-name PlainPing \
      -import-objc-header SimplePing.h \
      PlainPing.swift SimplePingAdapter.swift \
 && \
 echo "3. Compiling PlainPing" && \
 swiftc \
      -emit-object \
      -module-name PlainPing \
      -import-objc-header SimplePing.h \
      PlainPing.swift SimplePingAdapter.swift \
 && \
 echo "4. Compiling app" && \
 swiftc \
      -o app \
      -I . \
      -L . \
      *.o main.swift \
 && \
 echo "5. Running app" && \
 ./app
```

## Version using xcodebuild

Make sure to add `use_frameworks!` in the second line of `Podfile`.

Script (copy & paste into terminal):

```
echo "Compiling Pods" && \
pod install && \
xcodebuild -project Pods/Pods.xcodeproj \
&& \
echo "Compiling App" && \
dir="build/Pods.build/Release/PlainPing.build/Objects-normal/x86_64" && \
swiftc \
  -o app \
  -L "$dir" \
  -I "$dir" \
  main.swift \
  $(find $dir -name '*.o' -exec echo -n '{} ' \;) \
&& \
echo "Running App" && \
./app
```

## Sample main.swift

```
import Foundation
import PlainPing

PlainPing.ping("www.apple.com", withTimeout: 1.0, completionBlock: { (timeElapsed:Double?, error:Error?) in
    if let latency = timeElapsed {
        print("latency (ms): \(latency)")
    }

    if let error = error {
        print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
})

RunLoop.main.run()
```

Comment: It compiles, thanks a ton! One follow-up question, maybe you also know: while running generated application it fails with "Library not loaded". Seems that "swiftc" dynamically links into framework's library. Any way to force it a static (embed) link?

Comment: Also you can try build dependencies without generating Framework, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131476/compiling-and-linking-swift-plus-objective-c-code-from-the-os-x-command-line

Comment: All these answers are like "frameworks not supported for CLI apps". So there is no way to add Cocoapods library to my simple swift CLI app so it will work?

Comment: It also seems that swiftc sets "LC_RPATH" into "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx" so there seems no easy way for compiled application to load the framework.